# efficient method of storing a lot of text logs

Tags: memory, hard-drive, memory-efficient, storing-information

I have a lot of huge text logs due to running some tests continuously. All these log-files should be accessible during some period of time. But I faced with the problem when my 5TB hard drive was full. So I decided to archive my old logs using gzip and to write script which do the following: when my disk is full on 90% - delete all old archives. I am interesting about maybe more efficient ways of storing such type of files and quick access for them.

Comment: Have you looked at logrotate (http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_logrota.htm)?

Comment: not yet. Thanks. I'll look on it